# Finding a flight with flexible date AND flexible airports

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I want to find a roundtrip flight with flexible dates and flexible airports. Flightsfinder.com provided a nice price grid, but the airports are fixed. Does a flight finding service exist where it is possible to provide multiple airports (as in Booking.com) and flexible departure and arrival dates altogether ?

Comment: Google Flights?

Comment: By "flexible airports", do you mean that you want to be able to change arrival/destination airports even after buying the ticket?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://matrix.itasoftware.com/ can search multiple airports (both arrival and departure). You can either search +- 2 days or an entire month.

You can also specify (or exclude) specific airlines, alliances, layover cities, duration limits, etc.

Comment: Yes, it provides all the needed information. However, it says that I can't directly book the flight online. I have to visit a travel agent with all the codes for the final purchase.

Comment: Google Flights uses the exact same search engine and gives you a link for booking.

Comment: @ashfaq92 it's for _finding_ a flight. once you have decided which flight you want, you can book that online like any other; just not from a link directly from ita.

Comment: what is a recommended way to buy the ticket? Can I (not a travel agent) get access to whatever website it is that takes the code and money and gives tickets? If not, is there a cheep online travel agent service that would do that for minimal fees?

Comment: The best way is to book directly with the airline. In most cases you will get the same or a very similar price. On the rare occasions, that you don't you can try something like https://bookwithmatrix.com/  . Just cut and paste from matrix and they will give you bookable links. Recently they only show OneTravel and Priceline so they might have been bought.

Comment: @HanMah Once you've found the flight(s) that you want, then you can just search that particular route and date on the airline's website and you'll usually find the same flights and prices.

Answer (score 7):

[Kayak](https://www.kayak.com) will do this for you (at least for me, sitting in the US—its capabilities may be different elsewhere.)  For example, here are [the results for a 6-night round trip from the NYC area to the LA area.](https://www.kayak.com/flights/NYC-LAX/2022-08-16-flexible-2days/2022-08-22-flexible-2days/)

You do have to visit an external website (the airline or another third-party reseller) to actually book the ticket.  Unlike the ITA Matrix, though, Kayak provides the necessary links.

Comment: I prefer this view: https://www.kayak.com/explore/

Answer (score 0):

One can use the flight search engine [Kiwi](https://kiwi.com/en/) to find a roundtrip flight with flexible dates and flexible airports.

[Example](https://www.kiwi.com/us/?bags=1.1-&inboundDate=no-return&outboundDate=2022-12-26_2022-12-29&destination=san-francisco-california-united-states%2Coakland-california-united-states%2Csan-jose-california-united-states&origin=las-vegas-nevada-united-states%2Cseattle-washington-united-states):

[image]